# FormData not passed to PHP via Ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, slim

I'm after such flow:

1. user selects the file(s)
2. Ajax request(s) are fire up to the PHP backend
3. Photo processing
4. Output on the screen.

I am stuck on the step 2. For some reason, my PHP does not get the File object.

Here is my code.

a simple form with a `div#uploadZone` pretending drop zone for user's files.

```js
// file selected
$("#files").change(function() {
  for (var index = 0; index < $('#files')[0].files.length; index++) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', $('#files')[0].files[index]);
    fd.append('item', $('#record').val());
    // formData for console output
    console.table([...fd]);
    $(document).uploadPhoto($('#files')[0].files.length - 1, index, [...fd]);
  }
});

(function($) {
  $.fn.uploadPhoto = function(count, loopIndex, formData) {
    var index = loopIndex;
    var total = count;
    $.ajax({
      url: "/ajax/photo/new",
      method: "post",
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
    }).done(function(msg) {
      // show uploaded photos
      console.log('OK');
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, msg) {
      console.log('ERROR');
    });
  }
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<form action="/photo/new" id="uploadDataForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset class="pb-5">
    <div class="text-center p-4 idle" id="uploadZone">Drag & drop here</div>
    <input class="d-none" type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <div class="mt-4 pt-2 d-flex flex-wrap align-items-stretch" id="gallery-wrapper"></div>
    <input type="file " id="files " name="files[] " multiple>
    <input type="hidden " id="record " name="record " value="a1 ">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

When looking at the console, the result of console.table([...fd]) is:

```
| Index | 0    | 1  |
|-------|------|----|
| 0     |'file'|File|
| 1     |'item'|'a1'|
```

By expanding the details of the entry under [0] index, I'm able to see File meta data, i.e.:

- lastModified: 1685604952446
- lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 01 2023 09:35:52 GMT+0200
- name: "ef876689-004e-11ee-8b7f-c03ebabf9acb.jpg"
- size: 5410
- type: "image/jpeg"
- webkitRelativePath: ""

However, when I inspect data on **PHP**:

// Slim4 framework

```
$uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();
$this->logger->debug(var_dump($uploadedFiles));

// or like this
var_dump($_FILES));
```

Both outputs: null

I have no idea why output is null. Any ideas mates? I'm going crazy with this.

Comment: You have a missing `"` here `<div class="mt-4 pt-2 d-flex flex-wrap align-items-stretch" id="gallery-wrapper"></div>` I added it for you in the formatted code

Comment: `Both outputs: null`...how and where exactly are you seeing that? Were you inspecting it in the browser's Network tool following the AJAX request? Because in your JS code you only have `}).done(function(msg) {
      // show uploaded photos
      console.log('OK');` to process the response, so that wouldn't show it on the screen anywhere.

Comment: And with the space in `id="files "` the `$("#files")` selector won't work anyway, so it won't even run the handler and fire the request. Similar problem for `$("#record")` Fix that and there's no obvious client-side issue: https://jsfiddle.net/jto04aLz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your code, pass the `FormData` to your `uploadPhoto` properly. Also delete spaces from your HTML attributes otherwise the JS code wouldn't work at all (On the other hand the OP was able to POST. so probably spaces are just wrong example data):

```
$(document).uploadPhoto($('#files')[0].files.length - 1, index, fd);
```

[image]
Otherwise you have a wrong form payload:
[image]

Comment: That shouldn't cause a problem - see https://jsfiddle.net/q2df1v0x/

Comment: @ADyson you're wrong check the screenshots in the answer (updated)

Comment: Apologies yes i hadn't spotted that. It isn't the only issue though, as I've noted in comments on the main question

Comment: @ADyson i hope the author will handle the both inputs from us

Comment: @ADyson on the other hand the OP was able to POST. so probably spaces are just wrong example data

Comment: I'm not sure we actually have any 100% evidence of that. They claim to have seen some output, but it's not clear where from. As I pointed out above, they haven't written any code which would display the output from the AJAX request. It's possible they saw it in the Network tool but it wasn't clear. But hopefully yes it was just a typo when creating their question (but they then should ensure to use copy and paste in future!) :-)

Comment: Hi @AlexanderNenashev and ADyson. Thanks for your comments. When it comes to white spaces in the attributes name, I have no clue what happened during ctrl c & v. In the code editor, there are no whitespaces. All good there.
However, Alexander pointed out wrong passing of FormData -> was [...fd] which was obvious mistake (copied over from console debuging process). It has been corrected but with no change to the overall status. Still, no Files sent over to the PHP backend.

Comment: when it comes to null outputs, i see it in the PHP log file:
[2023-06-28T13:42:12.392685+02:00] [APP, DEBUG] [POST, 200, /ajax/photo/new]:
[2023-06-28T13:42:12.393571+02:00] [APP, DEBUG] [POST, 200, /ajax/photo/new]:

Both lines are produced because of two commands in PHP:
$this->logger->debug(var_dump($uploadedFiles));
$this->logger->debug(var_dump($_FILES));

Comment: In the dev tools, Network -> Payload over ajax request gives me the same/similar result as Alex posted on the screenshot.

Comment: @Kuba `var_dump` writes directly to the standard output stream, it does not return a value which could be passed to the logger function (See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). Check the raw Response to the AJAX request in the Network tool insead, in case you can see the var_dump output there. If you want to log the values, an alternative could be to use print_r with the `return` parameter set true (See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Comment: Hi ADyson, that's it! I noticed it had to be that bloody var_dump() thingy, by looking at Console -> Network -> request -> Preview, where var dump output was properly displayed. At the end, it was about passing formData properly + backend wrong usage of the var_dump() function, which was leading me to a wrong conslusion it was a client-side error.